# css modules with webpack lowercase file name

Tags: webpack, sass, css-modules

I have the following rule in my webpack.confg

```
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      query: {
        modules: true,
        sourceMap: true,
        importLoaders: 2,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      }
    },
    'sass-loader'
  ]
```

This works but my file names are upper case, e.g. `Label.scss`

Which means my class names come out as `Label__whatever__DRfgZ` for example.

Is there anyway to lowercase first part of the class that comes from the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Webpack >= 2.2.1, you can pass a [function](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#modules) to the loader options:

```
{
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
    getLocalIdent: (context, localIdentName, localName, options) => {
      return localIdentName.replace(/^./, string[0].toUpperCase());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I use the same generator function in .babelrc? 
Using SSR for react modules with a random generator gives different hashes on client and node.